# applying function or loop function

Tags: r

1.Let CFt denote cash flows at time t. Then, the present value is
PV=∑t( CFt/(1+i)t).

Consider the following cash flows: 100, 400, 1000, 3000, 100, 500.

Assume i=0.05 and compute PV
2. Implement a function that accepts a vector of cashflows and a parameter for i. The functions returns the PV
how to solve these problem can anyone tell me

Comment: How does the code look like which you already tried?

Comment: You may also need `t`?

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: just do `sum(cf/((1+i)^(seq_along(cf))))`. If you wanted to compute the `NPV` then add this to the negative cashflow at time zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function will look as shown below:

```
PV <- function(cf, i) sum(cf / ((1 + i)^(seq_along(cf))))
```

eg:

```
cashflows <- c(100, 400, 1000, 3000, 100, 500)
PV(cashflows, 0.05)
[1] 4241.455
```

Comparing this to what the package has:

```
FinancialMath::NPV(0, cashflows, seq(1, length(cashflows)),  0.05)
[1] 4241.455
```

Recall that `PV` is equivalent to `NPV` when the initial cash outflow is 0.